# How to check code integrity with SHA1 fingerprint?

Tags: android, kotlin, sha1, integrity

I would like to check code integrity where where an attacker could modify an Android application package (APK) without proper authorization.

I have created functions that check SHA1, if it the same as mine from `local.properties`

```
    private fun checkIntegrity() {
        val expectedSignature = BuildConfig.PROD_SHA1_SIGNATURE

        if (integrityChecker.checkCodeIntegrity(expectedSignature)) {
        } else {
            nonFatalLogger.logNonFatal(Exception(integrityChecker.getErrorMessageIntegrity()))
            integrityChecker.finishApplication()
        }
    }
```

```
    fun checkCodeIntegrity(expectedSignature: String): Boolean {
        val actualSignature = getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint()
        return actualSignature == expectedSignature
    }
```

```
    private fun getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint(): String? {
        val pm: PackageManager = context.packageManager
        val packageName: String = context.packageName
        var signatures: Array<Signature>? = null

        try {
            signatures = with(pm) {
                if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.P) {
                    getPackageInfoCompat(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNING_CERTIFICATES)
                        .signingInfo
                        .apkContentsSigners
                } else {
                    getPackageInfoCompat(packageName, PackageManager.GET_SIGNATURES)
                        .signatures
                }
            }
        } catch (e: PackageManager.NameNotFoundException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        val cert = signatures?.get(0)?.toByteArray()
        val input: InputStream = ByteArrayInputStream(cert)
        var cf: CertificateFactory? = null
        try {
            cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X509")
        } catch (e: CertificateException1) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        var c: X509Certificate? = null
        try {
            c = cf?.generateCertificate(input) as X509Certificate
        } catch (e: CertificateException1) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        var hexString: String? = null
        try {
            val md = MessageDigest.getInstance(SHA1_NAME)
            val publicKey = md.digest(c?.encoded)
            hexString = byte2HexFormatted(publicKey)
        } catch (e1: NoSuchAlgorithmException) {
            e1.printStackTrace()
        } catch (e: CertificateEncodingException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
        return hexString
    }
```

Everything works fine, but when I create `Signed Bundle/APK` or generate my app on bitrise  it goes to the else function `finishApplication` which means for me SHA1 is not the same as generated before? Why?
I have generated SHA1 from my release-keystore or `productionRelease` build and it is correct, but after launch apk from `Signed Bundle` it is not and I quite do not understand that.
Of course I could manage it, to `lognotfatal` error to firebase with my proper SHA1 from signed bundle apk, but first I would like to understand it and maybe instead of two SHA values in local.properties, use just one.

Comment: First, please bear in mind that any attacker who wants to can eliminate your test by modifying `checkIntegrity()` to return `true`, so your test will only catch inexperienced attackers at best. Beyond that, please bear in mind that if you are using Play App Signing that the signing key used by Google is different than the signing key that you use for what you upload to Google.

Comment: I know that, but let's say I just want to put obstacles in the way to potentially attacker. 
Fingerprints (MD5, SHA-1, and SHA-256 are the same and
I have checked my App signing key certificate it is the same as mine in local.properties. From these instructions: https://support.google.com/googleplay/android-developer/answer/9842756?hl=en#zippy=%2Cinstructions-for-apps-created-before-august%2Cupgrade-your-app-signing-key-to-enroll-into-play-app-signing%2Crequest-a-key-upgrade-for-all-installs-on-android-n-api-level-and-above

Comment: It is weird I am trying to log non fatal to my firebase and when I try to use String from getCertificateSHA1Fingerprint() method it does not log any issues like it can't be generated but I do not understand why? It works in normal production release build, but when I create signed apk it does not.